# Best script to restore multiple databases with SQL Server 2012?

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I have to restore around 60 SQL databases of different sizes. I googled to find a script to restore all databases after each other , just picking it 1 by 1 from my folder. I was not that successful, probably because I am quite new to SQL etc.

It can be either done in powershell or sql command line, what I found for now was something like this:

```
RESTORE DATABASE [db1] FROM  DISK = N'C:\folder\db1.bak' WITH  FILE = 1,  NOUNLOAD,  STATS = 10
GO
RESTORE DATABASE [db2] FROM  DISK = N'C:\folder\db2.bak' WITH  FILE = 1,  NOUNLOAD,  STATS = 10
GO
```

So what I would do is get the filenames from a certain folder and replace "db1.bak" etc. with the names I just picked from my folder and then run the script.

I know that there must be a smarter way, or is it maybe possible to "load" many .bak files into SSMS so the program will run them after each other?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Script of Collet with some adaptations worked for me.

First enable xp_cmdshell by running the following SQL commands:

```
-- To allow advanced options to be changed.  
EXEC sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1;  
GO  
-- To update the currently configured value for advanced options.  
RECONFIGURE;  
GO  
-- To enable the feature.  
EXEC sp_configure 'xp_cmdshell', 1;  
GO  
-- To update the currently configured value for this feature.  
RECONFIGURE;  
GO
```

Next, update the script below to restore the databases from the backup files. Replace `C:\Backup\` with your local directory containing your .BAK files and replace `C:\Microsoft SQL Server\SQLINSTANCE\MSSQL\DATA\` with your SQL Server data directory. This script also assumes the .BAK file names match the database names, otherwise the script will likely throw errors about logical file names not matching.

```
DECLARE @FilesCmdshell TABLE (
    outputCmd NVARCHAR (255)
)   
DECLARE @FilesCmdshellCursor CURSOR 
DECLARE @FilesCmdshellOutputCmd AS NVARCHAR(255)

INSERT INTO @FilesCmdshell (outputCmd) EXEC master.sys.xp_cmdshell 'dir /B  C:\Backup\*.bak'    
SET @FilesCmdshellCursor = CURSOR FOR SELECT outputCmd FROM @FilesCmdshell

OPEN @FilesCmdshellCursor
FETCH NEXT FROM @FilesCmdshellCursor INTO @FilesCmdshellOutputCmd
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN   
    DECLARE @sqlRestore NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'RESTORE DATABASE [' + SUBSTRING(@FilesCmdshellOutputCmd, 0, CHARINDEX('.', @FilesCmdshellOutputCmd)) + '] FROM  DISK = N''C:\Backup\' + SUBSTRING(@FilesCmdshellOutputCmd, 0, CHARINDEX('.', @FilesCmdshellOutputCmd)) + '.bak'' WITH  FILE = 1,  MOVE N''' + SUBSTRING(@FilesCmdshellOutputCmd, 0, CHARINDEX('.', @FilesCmdshellOutputCmd)) + ''' TO N''C:\Microsoft SQL Server\SQLINSTANCE\MSSQL\DATA\' + SUBSTRING(@FilesCmdshellOutputCmd, 0, CHARINDEX('.', @FilesCmdshellOutputCmd)) + '.mdf'',  MOVE N''' + SUBSTRING(@FilesCmdshellOutputCmd, 0, CHARINDEX('.', @FilesCmdshellOutputCmd)) + '_log'' TO N''C:\Microsoft SQL Server\SQLINSTANCE\MSSQL\DATA\' + SUBSTRING(@FilesCmdshellOutputCmd, 0, CHARINDEX('.', @FilesCmdshellOutputCmd)) + '_log.ldf'', NOUNLOAD,  STATS = 10'
    EXEC(@sqlRestore)

    FETCH NEXT FROM @FilesCmdshellCursor INTO @FilesCmdshellOutputCmd
END
```

Answer (score 2):

If your file names match with your db names, you can do something like this :

```
DECLARE @FilesCmdshell TABLE (
    outputCmd NVARCHAR (255)
)   
DECLARE @FilesCmdshellCursor CURSOR 
DECLARE @FilesCmdshellOutputCmd AS NVARCHAR(255)

INSERT INTO @FilesCmdshell (outputCmd) EXEC master.sys.xp_cmdshell 'dir /B  C:\folder\*.bak'    
SET @FilesCmdshellCursor = CURSOR FOR SELECT outputCmd FROM @FilesCmdshell

OPEN @FilesCmdshellCursor
FETCH NEXT FROM @FilesCmdshellCursor INTO @FilesCmdshellOutputCmd
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN   
    DECLARE @cmd NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'RESTORE DATABASE [' + SUBSTRING(@FilesCmdshellOutputCmd, 0, CHARINDEX('.', @FilesCmdshellOutputCmd)) + '] FROM  DISK = N''C:\folder\' + SUBSTRING(@FilesCmdshellOutputCmd, 0, CHARINDEX('.', @FilesCmdshellOutputCmd)) + '.bak'' WITH  FILE = 1,  NOUNLOAD,  STATS = 10'
    EXEC(@cmd)

    FETCH NEXT FROM @FilesCmdshellCursor INTO @FilesCmdshellOutputCmd
END
```

Answer (score 2):

The following Powershell script worked best for me.

Source: [Simon Osborne's SQL Blog](https://simonosbornesql.wordpress.com/2015/10/20/restoring-1000s-of-sql-server-databases-using-powershell/)

```
$backupRoot = Get-ChildItem -Path "D:\BAK_FILE_FOLDER"
$datafilesDest = "D:\DATA_FILE_FOLDER"
$logfilesDest = "D:\LOG_FILE_FOLDER"
$server = "server\inst" 

## For each folder in the backup root directory...
#
foreach($folder in $backupRoot)
{   
    # Get the most recent .bak files for all databases...
    $backupFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path $folder.FullName -Filter "*.bak" -Recurse | Sort-Object -Property CreationTime -Descending | Select-Object -First 1


    # For each .bak file...
    foreach ($backupFile in $backupFiles)
    {
        # Restore the header to get the database name...
        $query = "RESTORE HEADERONLY FROM DISK = N'"+$backupFile.FullName+"'"
        $headerInfo = Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance $server -Query $query
        $databaseName = $headerInfo.DatabaseName

        # Restore the file list to get the logical filenames of the database files...
        $query = "RESTORE FILELISTONLY FROM DISK = N'"+$backupFile.FullName+"'"
        $files = Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance $server -Query $query

        # Differentiate data files from log files...
        $dataFile = $files | Where-Object -Property Type -EQ "D"
        $logFile = $files | Where-Object -Property Type -EQ "L"

        # Set some variables...
        $dataFileName = $dataFile.LogicalName
        $logFileName = $logFile.LogicalName

        # Set the destination of the restored files...
        $dataFileFullPath = $datafilesDest+"\"+$dataFileName+".mdf"
        $logFileFullPath = $logfilesDest+"\"+$logFileName+".ldf"

        # Create some "Relocate" file objects to pass to the Restore-SqlDatabase cmdlet...
        $RelocateData = New-Object 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.RelocateFile, Microsoft.SqlServer.SmoExtended, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91' -ArgumentList $dataFileName, $dataFileFullPath
        $RelocateLog = New-Object 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.RelocateFile, Microsoft.SqlServer.SmoExtended, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91' -ArgumentList $logFileName, $logFileFullPath

        # Perform the database restore... and then go around the loop.
        Restore-SqlDatabase -ServerInstance $server -Database $databaseName -BackupFile $backupFile.FullName -RelocateFile @($RelocateData,$RelocateLog) -ReplaceDatabase
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same requirement and adapted the script found [here](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic401619-31-1.aspx), originally written by Chris Gallelli in 2003.

This version has been tested on SQL 2014.

Here is an example call to the Stored Procedure that does all the work:

```
EXEC master.dbo.spRestore_All_Backups_From_Folder 'C:\To Restore\'
```

The path obviously needs to be a path on the server that you are working against, not your own PC where you might be running SSMS from.

Here is the code for the Stored Procedure.

```
--Adapted from: https://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic401619-31-1.aspx

USE [master]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF
GO


/***************************************************************************************/
-- Purpose: 
-- Restore one or many database backups from a single directory. This script reads all
-- database backups that are found in the @restoreFromDir parameter.
-- Any file that matches the form %_FULL_% will be restored to
-- the file locations specified in the RestoreTo... parameter(s). 
-- The restored database name is determined from the headers in the backup file, so will 
-- match the originally backed up database.
-- We only prcoess FULL backups and ignore DIFF's or TRN's.
--
-- Input Parameters:    See below
-- Output Parameters:   None
-- Return Values:       None
--
-- Written By: Chris Gallelli -- 8/22/03
-- Modified By:
-- Modifications: Bruce Canaday -- 10/20/2003
-- Added optional parameters @MatchFileList and @DBName
-- Bruce Canaday -- 10/24/2003
-- Get the db name as the characters LEFT of the right most '_FULL_' in the bak filenaame
-- This is to handle databases such as ALIS_DB
-- Bruce Canaday -- 10/28/2003
-- When using @MatchFileList = 'Y' attempt to create any directory that doesn't exist
-- Bruce Canaday -- 11/04/2003
-- Allow spaces in the @restoreFromDir directory name
-- paul Wegmann -- 07/11/2012
-- Chnaged the create table to allow more feilds to support SQL Server 2008r2 and SQl Server 2012
-- create table @filelist (LogicalName varchar(255), PhysicalName varchar(255), Type varchar(20), FileGroupName varchar(255), Size varchar(20), MaxSize varchar(20),
-- FileId int,CreateLSN bit, DropLSN bit, UniqueID varchar(255),ReadOnlyLSn bit, ReadWriteLSN bit, backupSizeInBytes varchar(50), SourceBlockSize int,
-- FileGroupid Int, LogGroupGUID varchar(255),DifferentialBaseLSN varchar(255),DifferentialBaseGUID varchar(255),isReadOnly bit, IsPresent bit,TDEThumbprint varchar(255) )
-- Paul Wegmann -- 07/11/2012 changed from stored proc to set declare 
-- Nitin Varshney - 07/01/2017 1. changes for picking db name from backup file,
-- 2. Added secondary File Location
-- 3. With Recovery or without recovery option
-- 4. All bak file will be select from the folder
-- 5. Print all restore command.
--
-- 2018-01-04       Mike Zandvliet      Renamed to spRestore_All_Backups_From_Folder. Tidied up code. Many minor improvements. 
--                                      Now handles *.dat as well as .bak.
--                                      Updated for SQL 2014. No longer supports any SQL <2012.
--                                      Removed set/declare code added by Paul Wegmann for better clarity.
--                                      Now uses default data and log directories if none are supplied.
--                                      Added parameter @bitReplace_Existing_DB, allows you to overwrite existing db's.
--
-- Examples Calls:
-- EXEC dbo.spRestore_All_Backups_From_Folder 'G:\SQLBACKUP_File'
--
-- EXEC dbo.spRestore_All_Backups_From_Folder 'C:\sqldb\sql_backup', 'C:\sqldb\sql_data', 'C:\sqldb\sql_log' (if you use declare/set option then you don't have to use this command to restore)
--
/***************************************************************************************/


IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[spRestore_All_Backups_From_Folder]') AND type in (N'P', N'PC'))
DROP PROCEDURE [dbo].[spRestore_All_Backups_From_Folder]
GO



CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.spRestore_All_Backups_From_Folder
    @restoreFromDir varchar(255),                   --The directory where the database backups are located. Do not include a trailing slash.
    @restoreToDataDir nvarchar(512)= null,          --The directory where the data files (i.e. MDF) will be restored to. Leave blank to use the default database folder.
    @restoreToLogDir nvarchar(512) = null,          --The directory where the log files (i.e. LDF) will be restored to. Leave blank to use the default log folder.
    @restoreToSecondaryDataDir nvarchar(512) = null,    --Allows NDF files to be placed in a different location. Leave blank to use @restoreToDataDir instead.
    @recovery int = 1,                              --Set to 1 to use the option WITH RECOVERY, or 0 for WITH NORECOVERY
    @MatchFileList char(1) = 'N',                   --Set to 'Y' to restore to the same directory structure that is contained in the backup, creating the folders if necessary, and ignoring the @restoreToDataDir / @restoreToLogDir values.
                                                    --Also allows for secondary data files 'ndf' to to be in a different dir than mdf files
    @OneDBName varchar(255) = null,                 --Filters the list of .BAKs to just this single name. Takes the latest .BAK/.DAT file with this name.
    @bitReplace_Existing_DB bit = 0                 --Set to 1 to overwrite existing databases.
AS

SET NOCOUNT ON


DECLARE 
    @filename varchar(255),
    @cmd varchar(8000),
    @cmd2 varchar(500),
    @cmd3 varchar(255),
    @DataName varchar (255),
    @LogName varchar (255),
    @LogicalName varchar(255),
    @PhysicalName varchar(255),
    @Type varchar(20),
    @FileGroupName varchar(255),
    @Size varchar(20),
    @MaxSize varchar(20),
    @restoreToDir varchar(255),
    @searchName varchar(255),
    @dbName varchar(255),
    @PhysicalFileName varchar(255)


DECLARE @dirList TABLE (filename varchar(100))


DECLARE @filelist TABLE 
    (
    LogicalName varchar(255), 
    PhysicalName varchar(255), 
    Type varchar(20), 
    FileGroupName varchar(255), 
    Size varchar(20), 
    MaxSize varchar(20),
    FileId int,
    CreateLSN bit, 
    DropLSN bit, 
    UniqueID varchar(255),
    ReadOnlyLSn bit, 
    ReadWriteLSN bit, 
    backupSizeInBytes varchar(50), 
    SourceBlockSize int,
    FileGroupid Int, 
    LogGroupGUID varchar(255),
    DifferentialBaseLSN varchar(255),
    DifferentialBaseGUID varchar(255),
    isReadOnly bit, 
    IsPresent bit,
    TDEThumbprint varchar(255) 
    )

DECLARE @Dbnameheaders TABLE 
(
BackupName varchar(256), 
BackupDescription varchar(256), 
BackupType varchar(256), 
ExpirationDate varchar(256), 
Compressed varchar(256), 
Position varchar(256),
DeviceType varchar(256), 
UserName varchar(256), 
ServerName varchar(256), 
DatabaseName varchar(256), 
DatabaseVersion varchar(256), 
DatabaseCreationDate varchar(256),
BackupSize varchar(256), 
FirstLSN varchar(256), 
LastLSN varchar(256), 
CheckpointLSN varchar(256), 
DatabaseBackupLSN varchar(256), 
BackupStartDate varchar(256),
BackupFinishDate varchar(256), 
SortOrder varchar(256), 
CodePage varchar(256), 
UnicodeLocaleId varchar(256), 
UnicodeComparisonStyle varchar(256), 
CompatibilityLevel varchar(256),
SoftwareVendorId varchar(256), 
SoftwareVersionMajor varchar(256), 
SoftwareVersionMinor varchar(256), 
SoftwareVersionBuild varchar(256), 
MachineName varchar(256), 
Flags varchar(256),
BindingID varchar(256), 
RecoveryForkID varchar(256), 
Collation varchar(256), 
FamilyGUID varchar(256), 
HasBulkLoggedData varchar(256), 
IsSnapshot varchar(256), 
IsReadOnly varchar(256),
IsSingleUser varchar(256), 
HasBackupChecksums varchar(256), 
IsDamaged varchar(256), 
BeginsLogChain varchar(256), 
HasIncompleteMetaData varchar(256), 
IsForceOffline varchar(256),
IsCopyOnly varchar(256), 
FirstRecoveryForkID varchar(256), 
ForkPointLSN varchar(256), 
RecoveryModel varchar(256), 
DifferentialBaseLSN varchar(256), 
DifferentialBaseGUID varchar(256),
BackupTypeDescription varchar(256), 
BackupSetGUID varchar(256), 
CompressedBackupSize varchar(256), 
Containment varchar(256),
KeyAlgorithm nvarchar(32),
EncryptorThumbprint varbinary(20),
EncryptorType nvarchar(32)
);





--Process parameters
IF RIGHT(@restoreFromDir,1) = '\'
    SET @restoreFromDir = LEFT(@restoreFromDir, LEN(@restoreFromDir)-1)

IF ISNULL(@restoreToDataDir,'') = ''
    SET @restoreToDataDir = CAST(SERVERPROPERTY('InstanceDefaultDataPath') AS nvarchar(512))
    --EXEC master.dbo.xp_instance_regread N'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE', N'Software\Microsoft\MSSQLServer\MSSQLServer', N'DefaultData', @restoreToDataDir output

IF ISNULL(@restoreToLogDir,'') = ''
    SET @restoreToLogDir = CAST(SERVERPROPERTY('InstanceDefaultLogPath') AS nvarchar(512))
    --EXEC master.dbo.xp_instance_regread N'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE', N'Software\Microsoft\MSSQLServer\MSSQLServer', N'DefaultLog', @restoreToLogDir output

IF ISNULL(@restoreToSecondaryDataDir, '') = ''
    SET @restoreToSecondaryDataDir = @restoreToDataDir


--SELECT @restoreToDataDir, @restoreToLogDir, @restoreToSecondaryDataDir



--Get the list of database backups that are in the restoreFromDir directory. We only go with FULL backups and ignore DIFF's or TRN's.
IF @OneDBName IS NULL
    SELECT @cmd = 'dir /b /on "' + @restoreFromDir + '\*_FULL_*.*"'
ELSE
    SELECT @cmd = 'dir /b /o-d /o-g "' + @restoreFromDir + '\*_FULL_*.*"'


--select @cmd,'AllFiles' -- Give All Files in Backup Folder

INSERT @dirList EXEC master..xp_cmdshell @cmd




--select * from @dirList where filename like '%_FULL_%' --order by filename -- List all the files in backup folder
SELECT * FROM @dirList WHERE filename like '%.bak' OR filename LIKE '%.dat' ORDER BY filename -- List all the files in backup folder




IF @OneDBName IS NULL
    BEGIN
        DECLARE BakFile_csr cursor for
        SELECT * FROM @dirList where filename like '%.bak' or filename like '%.dat' order by filename
    END
ELSE
    BEGIN -- single db, don't order by filename, take default latest date /o-d parm in dir command above
        SELECT @searchName = @OneDBName + '_FULL_%'

        DECLARE BakFile_csr cursor for
        SELECT top 1 * FROM @dirList WHERE filename LIKE @searchName
    END


OPEN BakFile_csr
FETCH BakFile_csr INTO @filename

WHILE @@fetch_status = 0
    BEGIN
        SELECT @cmd = "RESTORE FILELISTONLY FROM disk = '" + @restoreFromDir + "\" + @filename + "'"
        INSERT @filelist EXEC ( @cmd )

        --identify the db name from backup file
        SELECT @cmd3 = "RESTORE HEADERONLY FROM disk = '" + @restoreFromDir + "\" + @filename + "'"
        INSERT @Dbnameheaders EXEC (@cmd3)

        SELECT @dbName = DatabaseName FROM @Dbnameheaders
        --identify the db name from backup file [END Here]


        IF @OneDBName is null
            SELECT @dbName = @dbName --left(@filename,datalength(@filename) - patindex('%_FULL_%',reverse(@filename))-3)
        ELSE
            SELECT @dbName = @OneDBName


        SELECT @cmd = "RESTORE DATABASE [" + @dbName + "] FROM DISK = '" + @restoreFromDir + "\" + @filename + "' WITH "
        --Example: RESTORE DATABASE [HCPPREPROD] FROM DISK = 'C:\To Restore\HCPPREPROD_FULL_20180103.dat' WITH 

        PRINT 'RESTORING DATABASE ' + @dbName

        --Select * from @filelist ---List of files in backupfile all mdf,ndf,ldf


        DECLARE DataFileCursor cursor for
        SELECT LogicalName, PhysicalName, Type, FileGroupName, Size, MaxSize
        FROM @filelist

        OPEN DataFileCursor
        FETCH DataFileCursor INTO @LogicalName, @PhysicalName, @Type, @FileGroupName, @Size, @MaxSize

        WHILE @@fetch_status = 0
            BEGIN
                IF @MatchFileList != 'Y'
                    BEGIN -- RESTORE with MOVE option
                        SELECT @PhysicalFileName = REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(RTRIM(@PhysicalName)),1,patindex('%\%',reverse(rtrim(@PhysicalName)))-1 ))

                        IF @Type = 'L'
                            SELECT @restoreToDir = @restoreToLogDir
                        ELSE IF @PhysicalFileName LIKE '%.ndf'
                            SELECT @restoreToDir = @restoreToSecondaryDataDir
                        ELSE
                            SELECT @restoreToDir = @restoreToDataDir

                        IF RIGHT(@restoreToDir, 1) = '\'
                            SET @restoreToDir = LEFT(@restoreToDir, LEN(@restoreToDir)-1)

                        --SELECT @LogicalName, @restoreToDir, @PhysicalFileName
                        SELECT @cmd = @cmd + " MOVE '" + @LogicalName + "' TO '" + @restoreToDir + "\" + @PhysicalFileName + "', "

                    END
                ELSE
                    BEGIN -- Match the file list, attempt to create any missing directory
                        SELECT @restoreToDir = left(@PhysicalName,datalength(@PhysicalName) - patindex('%\%',reverse(@PhysicalName)) )
                        SELECT @cmd2 = "if not exist " +@restoreToDir+ " md " +@restoreToDir
                        EXEC master..xp_cmdshell @cmd2
                    END


                FETCH DataFileCursor INTO @LogicalName, @PhysicalName, @Type, @FileGroupName, @Size, @MaxSize

            END -- DataFileCursor loop

        CLOSE DataFileCursor
        DEALLOCATE DataFileCursor



        IF @recovery = 0
            SELECT @cmd = @cmd + ' NORECOVERY, STATS = 5'
        ELSE
            SELECT @cmd = @cmd + ' RECOVERY, STATS = 5'



        IF @bitReplace_Existing_DB = 1
            SELECT @cmd = @cmd + ', REPLACE'

        SELECT @cmd 'x6'

        IF @bitReplace_Existing_DB = 0 AND DB_ID(@dbName) IS NOT NULL
            PRINT 'Database already exists - skipping... ' + @dbName
        ELSE
            EXEC (@cmd)


        DELETE FROM @filelist
        DELETE FROM @Dbnameheaders

        FETCH BakFile_csr INTO @filename

    END -- BakFile_csr loop

CLOSE BakFile_csr
DEALLOCATE BakFile_csr



RETURN 

GO
```

You will need to enable CMDSHELL in order to execute the SP. This script checks if you need to change anything:

```
USE [master]
GO

IF (SELECT CONVERT(INT, ISNULL(value, value_in_use)) AS config_value FROM  sys.configurations WHERE  name = 'xp_cmdshell') = 0
    PRINT 'You need to enable CMDSHELL'
ELSE
    PRINT 'CMDSHELL is already enabled, you can now run the SP.'
```

Here is how to enable CMDSHELL:

```
EXEC sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1
GO
RECONFIGURE
GO
EXEC sp_configure 'xp_cmdshell', 1
GO
RECONFIGURE
GO
```

Answer (score 1):

in recent SQL version there is new Column "SnapshotUrl" so small modifications is required:

```
DECLARE @filelist TABLE 
(
LogicalName varchar(255), 
PhysicalName varchar(255), 
Type varchar(20), 
FileGroupName varchar(255), 
Size varchar(20), 
MaxSize varchar(20),
FileId int,
CreateLSN bit, 
DropLSN bit, 
UniqueID varchar(255),
ReadOnlyLSn bit, 
ReadWriteLSN bit, 
backupSizeInBytes varchar(50), 
SourceBlockSize int,
FileGroupid Int, 
LogGroupGUID varchar(255),
DifferentialBaseLSN varchar(255),
DifferentialBaseGUID varchar(255),
isReadOnly bit, 
IsPresent bit,
TDEThumbprint varchar(255),
SnapshotUrl varchar(255) 
)
```