# Dynamic restore multiple databases from a folder

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-restore

I am tasked with restoring several SQL Server databases from `.bak` files generated from another server in another organization. I need to be able to add automation to this process as it will have to occur daily.

The challenge I am having is that the `.bak` files have different names every day, like: `DatabaseName_Full_Backup_Date_Time_xxxxxx.bak`. Also the data and log files need to be moved (`MOVE`) during the restore to my server's data and log file locations.

I decided to use T-SQL, hoping to find a robust solution that could be implemented from a SQL Server Agent scheduled job that restores the databases, applies the original permissions, and moves\drops the old `.bak` files to an archive location.

I tried solving this with PowerShell but the `-relocate` file did not work. Also tried this stored procedure (`dbo.spRestore_All_Backups_From_Folder`) proposed [on this website here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19428189/best-script-to-restore-multiple-databases-with-sql-server-2012) which is very close to what I need but in my SQL Server 2016 machine, I get an error when restoring backups generated from another server.

The script works with `.bak` files from databases that have been backed up on the same server and no MOVE of files is needed.

The error I get when I attempt a restore of a `.bak` file from another server is:

> Msg 213, Level 16, State 7, Line 300
>   Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition.
>
> Msg 3013, Level 16, State 1, Line 300
>   RESTORE FILELIST is terminating abnormally.

Thank you for all input and advice!